# Javascript function in href with argument and parameter

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I was trying to change the content to another page content such as textbox with the pervious information inside the textbox. Something like edit.

I could not add in the parameter that I want to get

`Response.Write("<a href=" & "javascript:ajaxpage('edit.aspx?jobID=" & row("jobID") & "'&time=" & row1("time") & "&status=" & row1("timeStatus") & "&action=" & row1("actionDone") & "&report=R,'add');" & ">ActionDone</a>" & row1("actionDone"))`

Some how it does not work but  it work with this:

`Response.Write("<a href=" & "javascript:ajaxpage('getData.aspx','add');" & ">ActionDone</a>")`

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve and give us some more context?

Comment: Why are you using Response.Write with .NET?

Comment: i trying to get another page content to replace with the content it have in the column.

Comment: I use Response.Write because there is conditional what info it  needed to display out.